# In jmeter How to push the jtl result to MySQL database automatically and inserting those values into table,which custom code ,groovy script are used

Tags: mysql, jmeter

How Do that,in jmeter by using JDbc or JSr223sampler,after completion of execution generate jtl/CSV results file,to take the results file particular values like samplers,average response time,90 percentage values and convert milli seconds and push to mysql DB,how do the process tell,which query use and which groovy codes are written in samplers?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the CSV files containing the metrics you want to store using [JMeter Plugins Command Line tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) (it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

Once done you can import the CSV file into MySQL database like it's described in [MySQL Workbench Manual  > Table Data Export and Import Wizard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html)